# HTML tags in dataframe as per conditions

Tags: r

I am trying to incorporate html tags in dataframe as per the conditions. But getting below error. Can anyone help

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("a","b"))
if(asd$a == "a"){
  asd$new <- HTML('<span>',asd$a,'</span>','<span> R</span>')
} else {
  asd$new <- asd$a
}
Warning message:
In if (asd$a == "a") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Expected output

```
asd
a    new
  
a    <span>',a,'</span>','<span> R</span>
b    b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try -

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("a","b"))
asd$new <- asd$a
inds <- which(asd$a == "a")
asd$new[inds] <- htmltools::HTML('<span>',asd$a[inds],'</span>','<span> R</span>')
asd

#  a                              new
#1 a <span> a </span> <span> R</span>
#2 b                                b
```

If there are more than one value in the dataframe that satisfies the condition you may have to use `sapply`.

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("a","b", "a"))
asd$new <- asd$a
inds <- which(asd$a == "a")
asd$new[inds] <- sapply(asd$a[inds], function(x)
                htmltools::HTML('<span>',x,'</span>','<span> R</span>'))
asd
```

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot